# Where can I learn about MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I watched the DNR TV episode with Glenn Block and it looks like MEF would be useful for my company.  I am trying to find out more information on it's strengths and weaknesses and some sample projects that use it.  Are there any good blogs/tutorials on using MEF?

Note: I use C#, so if the examples are in C#, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I haven't found a really comprehensive page, but there are a few:

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)

[Simple Example from a msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/20/simple-example-using-managed-extensibility-framework-in-silverlight.aspx)

[Code Project's Introduction to MEF (part 1)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37559/Managed-Extensibility-Framework-Part-1)

[MEF 101 part A from Geek with Blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122134754/http://geekswithblogs.net/malisancube/archive/2009/05/26/managed-extensibility-framework-101---a.aspx)

[MEF 101 part B](https://web.archive.org/web/20201125115104/http://geekswithblogs.net/malisancube/archive/2009/06/09/managed-extensibility-framework-101-b.aspx)

[Another MSDN blog, a little more history than tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2008/04/25/MEF.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

Mike Taulty recently did a set of [screencasts](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924164616/http://mtaulty.com:80/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/31/silverlight-4-screencasts-the-managed-extensibility-framework-mef.aspx) on using MEF in Silverlight, which should be a good introduction to MEF.

Answer (score 14):

I've done an ever growing series on MEF from the very basics into more advanced stuff planned in the near future.

http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2009/11/working-with-managed-extensibility.html

Comment: I could have give +10 for you, its really excellent article James, Beginners I highly recommend to start from here.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [this MEF demo article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SoapBoxCorePinBallDemo.aspx) on CodeProject, and all the code is open sourced.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) is a good start

[Kathleen Dollard](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kathleen/) has some good materials as well

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for information on the latest version of MEF that is shipping with the next .NET Framework, the definitive source of information is the [BCL Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329030441/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/tags/mef/) on MSDN.

(MEF is part of the .NET Base Class Libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann has a section on MEF, as well as Castle Windsor, StructureMap, Spring.NET, Autofac, and Unity.